# Reversing the polarity on a relay

Tags: relay, polarity

I have a single coil latching relay ([HFD2/012-S-L2](https://source.hongfa.com//Api/DownloadPdf/323)): + & - to set and - & + to reset.
I have a 12 V supply to trigger the relay (via a push-button switch).

My question is this - how to get the polarity to reverse on each press of the button, so the same supply will set and reset the relay?

Does that make sense?

Comment: Is it a latching relay you have or a normal one? Can you provide a part number?

Comment: Does it have to be a pushbutton? It would be easy to do with a DPDT center off momentary toggle or rocker switch.

Comment: Hi, the part number is: HFD2/012-S-L2

Comment: Welcome! For future reference, we expect part number and link to datasheet in your questions. I've taken the liberty to add in the information for you.

Comment: The part number HFD2/012-S-L2 is for a two-coil latch relay. The correct part number for a single-coil latch relay is HFD2/012-S-L1.

Answer (score 4):

> on each press of the button,

Since you don't say what that "button" is, I'll pick one for you: the button at the top of a [Push-on/push-off alternating SPDT switch](https://www.digikey.com/short/78vbc818).

1. Feed the DC voltage to the two NC, NO contacts of the SPDT switch.
2. Connect the common contact of the SPDT switch to invert the DC voltage at each press (positive out -- press switch -- 0 V output -- press switch -- positive output -- etc.)
3. Feed that voltage to the relay coil through a capacitor to create a pulse of current (you will have to play with the value to get a sufficient pulse)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWXrAS.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Each time you press the switch, the voltage at its output changes and the current into the relay coil sees a pulse of current of alternating sign.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a solution using an SPDT toggle switch and an electrolytic capacitor.

[image]

The latch relay is set in one position of the switch and reset in the other,
as the capacitor charges / discharges through the relay coil.

Answer (score 2):

This could be done with a DPDT center-off momentary switch. You connect the power supply to the poles and then cross-connect the throws so switching one way sets the relay, switching the other unsets it, and in the center-off position the relay retains it's current state.

Here's the schematic and how a typical switch would be wired.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fifZa7.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: @DavideAndrea No it doesn't, unless someone stands there and holds the switch closed. It's a center off momentary switch. The schematic editor doesn't have the correct symbol but I added the text to indicate that and it says it in the answer.

Comment: Sorry. I missed that. On another note: did you notice that OP asked: "how to get the polarity to reverse _on each press of the button_?"

Comment: @DavideAndrea Yes. I figured I'd present this as an alternative approach, the end result is the the same, the relay sets and unsets, it just uses a rocker switch (which are actually sold as motor reversing switches, same idea just connected to a motor instead of relay coil) instead of a pushbutton.

Answer (score 1):

This is tricky, because you're asking a latching relay to work in a manner it's not intended to.  I would recommend using a different latching relay, which is more suited to the sequencing you desire, or simply eliminate the relay and carry current through a push-on push-off switch.

Doing this in relay-state technology is possible, but messy. I'm really not a fan, in a world full of Arduinos.

However, if you want to use this relay, the problem is you need something that stores the state the relay is in, so it can actuate *when it's in the wrong state*.  I would use a push-on push-off button as Davide Andrea suggests to be the "storage flip-flop".  Then you have it pick up a relay if "on", and have the output of your latching relay pick up another relay if "on", and if those two relays disagree, shoot the appropriate voltage at the latching relay coil until they agree.

And that would be a lot easier to do with the style of latching relay with a 3-wire coil: a common, an "energize for on", and "energize for off" wire.